# asp.net core 2.1 and windows impersonation with httpclient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

i'm using asp.net core mvc 2.1 and need to make calls to a legacy asp.net 4.6 webapi endpoint that depends on Windows Authentication to authenticate and authorize the user's calls.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2#work-with-windows-authentication) details how to impersonate a windows identity and I got it working...**BUT** the next sentence on that page also says

> Note that RunImpersonated doesn't support asynchronous operations and
>   shouldn't be used for complex scenarios. For example, wrapping entire
>   requests or middleware chains **isn't supported or recommended**.

**My Question:**

If it "shouldn't be used" then what is the preferred way to impersonate the user when making calls within a windows domain? In asp.net framework you could simply add a `<identity impersonate="true" />` node to the web.config

Comment: An outgoing request isn't a complex scenario, what other kind of answer do you expect?  You said you had it working.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks for taking the time to reply... 1: I am expecting an answer to the question of "what is the preferred way".  2: I think that "complex scenario" is a bit vague, and while I agree with you that a simple _httpClient.GetStringAsync("/api/program").Result doesnt sound complex to me.  3. I've been doing this long enough to know "it worked on my machine" is no excuse after deployment.  if the answer is "No that is the preferred", I'm more than willing to accept that.   thanks

Comment: There is no other solution for `impersonate a windows identity` in asp.net core. If you need `impersonate`, this is the only way currently.

Comment: thanks @TaoZhou, add as an answer so I can give credit

Comment: @kevcoder I agree with you entirely, did you ever find a supported solution to this problem?

Comment: @P.Roe: No. This is the only solution. If you in a windows environment, then just stick with the full framework. To be honest my choice of core in this instance was more than a little bit of resume-driven-design :). I deleted that solution and returned to MVC5... and just shipped to production yesterday. Good luck

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution from comment:

There is no other solution for impersonate a windows identity in asp.net core. If you need impersonate, this is the only way currently in asp.net core.